# Inspect native date pickers on iOS and Android mobile devices

Tags: c#, mobile, appium

Does anyone know how to inspect the calendar element which is native to the iOS and Android mobile devices. It's not from an input field on a native mobile app, just a website opened on a mobile device. The inspect tool on chrome isn't able to click on it, only the elements behind it. I've tried Android studio as well but that Layout inspector appears to only work on native mobile apps, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

[image]